# How to hide / show the form that I want with the right fields

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, forms

- Hi ! I need help, I want to know how to hide or display a form. I have 2 forms, a studentForm and EmployeeForm When selected from the drop down list profileType I want her displays the form that corresponds to the selected profileType
- I do not know if it's my jQuery does not work or Create an account for the employee form does not work. I don't see why it does not work. I take my information from the database for the form fields.**
- I do not know why I have this error for the second because the first button works well and saves the information in my database in the right fields
- For finish i have a error because in my template display both forms appear simultaneously and only the first boutton (Créer un compte)create an account works, while the second for EmployeeForm form does not work and returns an error (I put the image link to the error at the bottom)

Thanks you for your time and your help ! I am blocked !

========================================================================

> This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Faculte(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    couleur = models.CharField(max_length=6)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nom

class Personne(models.Model):
    matricule = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_de_naissance = models.DateField()
    courriel = models.EmailField()
    tel_fixe = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank =True)
    tel_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mot_de_passe = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    amis = models.ManyToManyField("self",blank =True)
    faculte = models.ForeignKey(Faculte)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.prenom + " " + self.nom


class Campus(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    adresse_postale = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom

class Fonction(models.Model):
    intitule = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.intitule


class Cursus(models.Model):
    intitule = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.intitule

class Employe(Personne):
    bureau = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    campus = models.ForeignKey(Campus)
    fonction = models.ForeignKey(Fonction)


class Etudiant(Personne):
    Cursus = models.ForeignKey(Cursus)
    annee = models.IntegerField()

class Message(models.Model):
    auteur = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    contenu = models.TextField()
    date_de_publication = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        if len(self.contenu) > 20:
            return self.contenu[:19] + "..."
        else:
            return self.contenu
```

> This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from polls.forms import LoginForm, StudentProfileForm, EmployeeProfileForm
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse

def welcome(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/welcome.html')

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the webtrial index.")

def login(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('polls/welcome')
    else:
        form= LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'polls/login.html', {'form':form})

    return render_to_response('polls/login.html', {'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def register(request):
    # if request.method=="GET":
    if len(request.GET) > 0 and 'profileType' in request.GET:
        studentForm = StudentProfileForm(prefix="st")
        employeeForm = EmployeeProfileForm(prefix="em")
        if request.GET['profileType'] == 'student':
            studentForm = StudentProfileForm(request.GET, prefix="st")
            if studentForm.is_valid():
                studentForm.save(commit=True)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('login/')
            elif request.GET['profileType'] == 'employee':
                employeeForm = EmployeeProfileForm(request.GET, prefix="em")
                if employeeForm.is_valid():
                    employee.save(commit=True)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('login/')
            return render(request, 'polls/user_profile.html',{'studentForm': studentForm, 'employeeForm': employeeForm})
    else:
        studentForm = StudentProfileForm(prefix="st")
        employeeForm = EmployeeProfileForm(prefix="em")
        return render(request, 'polls/user_profile.html',{'studentForm': studentForm, 'employeeForm': employeeForm},)
```

> this is my base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
{% csrf_token %}

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <title>Webtrial - {% block title %}Bienvenue !{%endblock %}</title>
    </head>

    <body id="{% block bodyId %}genericPage{% endblock %}">
        <header>
        {% block headerContent %}{% endblock %}
        </header>
        <section id="content">
            {% block content %}
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css"/>
                <!-- //LIEN DU JAVASCRIPT ICI  -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            {% endblock %}  
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

> This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from polls import views
from polls.views import welcome, login, register
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^register/', views.register),
    url(r'^login/',views.login),
    url(r'^', views.login)
]
```

> This is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from polls.models import Personne, Etudiant, Employe

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Courriel')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Mot de passe', widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super (LoginForm, self).clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")

        if email and password:
            result = Personne.objects.filter(mot_de_passe=password, courriel=email)

            if len(result) != 1:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Adresse de courriel ou mot de passe erroné(e).")
        return cleaned_data

class StudentProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Etudiant
        exclude =('amis',)

class EmployeeProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employe 
        exclude = ('amis',)
```

> This is my user_profile.html (location where the forms located and jquery)

```
{% extends "polls/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Création d'un profil{% endblock %}
{% block bodyId %}userProfilePage{% endblock %}
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#column_select").change(function() {
        if($("#profilType").val() == "student") {
            $('#employeeForm').hide();
            $('#studentForm').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#studentForm').hide();
            $('#employeeForm').show();
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function())
});
</script>
{% block content %}


<h1>Création d'un compte</h1>

<form>
    <p>
        <label for="profileType">Vous êtes :</label>
        <select name ="profileType" id="profilType">
            <option value="student">Etudiant</option>
            <option value="employee">Employe</option>

        </select>
    </p>
</form>

<div id="studentForm" class="student">
    <form action="register" method="GET" id="studentForm">
        {{ studentForm.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="profileType" value="student" />
            <input type="submit" value="Créer un compte" />
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="employeeForm" class="employee">
    <form action="register" method="GET" id="employeeForm">
        {{ employeeForm.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="profileType" value="employee" />
            <input type="submit" value="Créer un compte" />     
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css"/>
{% endblock %}
```

[This is the error for the second button "Créer un compte" (create an account)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ueygf.png)

[This is the template display link 'user_profile.html'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5WQf.png)

Comment: You're overcomplicating the issue by providing too way much information. Try to work out whether the problem is a presentational issue (both forms are there but you're failing to show or hide the right one), a problem with which forms you're delivering to the client, or a problem with what data you're receiving from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery onchange function is set to trigger on the `column_select` element; however, you don't have an element with that ID. Presumably you meant `#profilType` there.